# Inserting items in the middle of a grid using jquery masonry

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry

I am working on updating my gallery website, which is using masonry to lay out all of the images.  I want to have a contact panel open up in the middle of the masonry bricks upon clicking on the contact link.

Is there a way to insert the new bricks after the third DIV instead of simply appending or prepending them?

Is this possible with just masonry, or is this something that requires me to switch to isotope?

I tried using .after instead of .prepend, but that doesn't seem to be a workable option:

http://lilyinblue.com/gridtest.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can insert the content and then 'reload' the masonry.  Below is a basic version of what you could do.  You would replace the bit you have where you're wiring up the contact button with this.  You might want to set a flag when you add the contact information so that it's not added multiple times, or give a way to remove the contact information (like a close button) - that's all up to you.

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $('#contactlink').click(function(){
        var $container = $('#container');
        var contactDiv = $('<div class="element">To contact me please call 555-8723</div>');
        contactDiv.insertAfter($container.find('.element').eq(3));
        $container.masonry('reload');
    });
});
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you.  Also, thank you for the suggestion of adding a flag to not add the contact info multiple times.  I definitely would not have thought of that.

Comment: You're welcome.  I have only played with that masonry plugin a couple of times but I like it.  It looks like you got it working which is great.  Also, if it's working fine, you could accept the answer so others can use it as a reference later.